# Should a private class that is nested in a generic class be generic as well?

Tags: java, c#, generics

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private class NestedWrapper
    {
        T Value;
    }
    private NestedWrapper MyNested;
}
```

or

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private class NestedWrapper<S>
    {
        S Value;
    }
    private NestedWrapper<T> MyNested;
}
```

In C# is there any real difference between these two approaches? Other then additional `<T>` in the second one.

Note that being private is somewhat important since the nested class will not be accessible outside. And we can assume that the `NestedWrapper` class will **always** share the generic type `T` with its "parent".

**EDIT:** I'm actually going through `AtomicMarkableReference` implementation in Java: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference-source.html I'm reimplementing this class (which is a part of the Java's standard library) in C#. And as you can see in Java the second style is used. I'm not even sure if the first style is valid in Java (since I'm no Java programmer) but still we have two possible approaches for that in C#. I'm just wondering if there is any reason to prefer one over another.

Comment: Does it matter if it's a private class anyway?

Comment: @DavidG Maybe not? What if we assume that it is not private?

Comment: If you aren't ever going to specify anything other than the same generic type `T` that the containing class is using, then it just adds noise, so don't. If you *do* need to handle a different type, then you have no other option.

Comment: Do you have any use case where `T` and `S` would ever differ? If not, the second is just more complicated for no benefit.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more specific: does it affect performance and/or compilation process? Can a compiler do something with one something that it cannot do with the other?

Comment: Adding superfluous type parameters isn't going to *improve* performance. It should also not affect it negatively in a measurable way, though. It's some extra metadata and an additional type specification, not a big deal. The different semantics mean you should not choose between these based on any performance considerations, but based on what actually makes the most sense and has the least moving parts.

Comment: Concentrate on writing *clear, readable code*. Only if/when you have a performance *issue* should you start looking into alternatives (and then, ideally, just measure the alternatives to see if they make a difference)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've been reading through http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference-source.html which is Java but still. In that code (which is a part of the standard library) there's a private **generic** class inside. And the generic type is the same as the top generic type. It just made me wonder why.

Comment: Java and C# have completely different implementations of generics. They even have different opinions on what `private` means. Be very weary of transporting knowledge from one to the other. If you wanted to post a question on why *Java* does this, you'd probably get more insightful answers -- there's likely a good reason for it, but it does not generalize to private classes in C# generic classes *in general*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm actually reimplementing this Java code in C#. So maybe (maybe not) I need that knowledge in the C# world.

Comment: Well, in C#, you wouldn't do this. So it's very important to know why in Java, they do. But you need *Java* experts for that, not C# experts. (Well, ideally both, but I'm definitely no Java expert.) I'd advise you to make a question specific to this case -- especially since it's apparently about *concurrent* code, which is its own bag of trouble with different semantics. There may be alternatives that mean reimplementing this code is not even what you really need.

Comment: Any really, what exactly is opinion-based about my question? Either there is a real difference or no, how is that opinion-based?

Comment: That's not the question title. The latter says "Should a private class that is nested in a generic class be generic as well?" which _is_ asking for opinion-based answers. So maybe you want to change the title accordingly.

Comment: @Fildor I'm not good with titles. The original one sounds like a good summary to me. But if you have any suggestions about the title I'll be more than happy to change it.

Comment: I admit it's kind of hard to come up with one for this question, that avoids sounding like "give me opinions"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any real difference between these two approaches?

Yes, there *is* a real difference, because `NestedWrapper` has its own type parameter, independent of `Foo`'s own type parameter. Hence the *actual* types may be completely unrelated.

In the first case, `T` is fixed within `NextedWrapper` and you have no chance to create a wrapper for another type.

In the second case, the following is perfectly fine:

```
private NestedWrapper<T> nestedWrappedT;
private NestedWrapper<int> nestedWrappedInt;
private NestedWrapper<string> nestedWrappedString;
```

The fact it is `private` alone makes no difference.

Comment: Nothing stops you from declaring `private Foo<int>.NestedWrapper nestedWrappedInt;` in the first case.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh yeah, you are right. My point mainly was regarding the independence of those two types.

Answer (score 0):

In first approach, `T` is set for your outer class and then wherever is used in a class, it cannot be changed (without additional generic type, you are bound to `T`).

In second approach, you can set generic type independently for outer and inner class. But, since this class is private, you won't be able to set this generic parameter from outside your class.

The difference is that you have generic class inside your class (second approach). And you can choose any type to use it with inside your class.
But you have no control over it from outside of the class.

In your first approach, you can decide from outside of the class which type should be used in your inner class. You have control from the outside over the generic type passed to inner class.